# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound - in a descendant class' associated_controller#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am attempting to locate a parent object in a nested controller, so that I can associate the descendant resource with the parent like so:

```
# teams_controller.rb <snippet only>

def index
  @university = Univeresity.find(params[:university_id])
  @teams = @university.teams
end
```

When I call `find(params[:university_id])` per the snippet above & in line 6 of teams_controller.rb,  I receive ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound - Couldn't find University without an ID.

I'm not only interested in fixing this issue, but would also enjoy a better understanding of finding objects without having to enter a University.find(1) value, since I grant Admin the privilege of adding universities.

The Rails Guides say the following about the two kinds of parameters in a website:

> **3 Parameters**
>
> You will probably want to access data sent in by the user or other
>   parameters in your controller actions. There are two kinds of
>   parameters possible in a web application. The first are parameters
>   that are sent as part of the URL, called query string parameters. The
>   query string is everything after “?” in the URL. The second type of
>   parameter is usually referred to as POST data. This information
>   usually comes from an HTML form which has been filled in by the user.
>   It’s called POST data because it can only be sent as part of an HTTP
>   POST request. Rails does not make any distinction between query string
>   parameters and POST parameters, and both are available in the params
>   hash in your controller:

It continues a little further down, explaining that the params hash is an instance of HashWithIndifferentAccess, which allows usage of both symbols and strings interchangeably for the keys.

From what I read above, my understanding is that Rails recognizes both parameters (URL & POST) and stores them in the same hash (params).

Can I pass the params hash into a find method in any controller action, or just the create/update actions? I'd also be interested in finding a readable/viewable resource to understand the update_attributes method thats called in a controller's 'update' action.

Please overlook the commented out code, as I am actively searching for answers as well.

Thanks in advance.

Here are the associated files and server log.

## Webrick

[image]

teams_controller.rb

```
class TeamsController < ApplicationController
  # before_filter :get_university
  # before_filter :get_team

  def index
    @university = University.find(params[:univeristy_id])
    @teams = @university.teams
  end

  def new
    @university = University.find(params[:university_id])
    @team = @university.teams.build
  end

  def create
    @university = University.find(params[:university_id])
    @team = @university.teams.build(params[:team])
    if @team.save
      redirect_to [@university, @team], success: 'Team created!'
    else
      render :new, error: 'There was an error processing your team'
    end
  end

  def show
    @university = University.find(params[:university_id])
    @team = @university.teams.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
    @university = University.find(params[:university_id])
    @team = @university.teams.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @university = University.find(params[:university_id])
    @team = @university.teams.find(params[:id])
    if @team.update_attributes(params[:team])
      redirect_to([@university, @team], success: 'Team successfully updated')
    else
      render(:edit, error: 'There was an error updating your team')
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @university = University.find(params[:university_id])
    @team = @university.teams.find(params[:id])
    @team.destroy
    redirect_to university_teams_path(@university)
  end

  private 
  def get_university
    @university = University.find(params[:university_id]) # can't find object without id
  end

  def get_team 
    @team = @university.teams.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

team.rb

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :sport_type, :university_id

  has_many :home_events, foreign_key: :home_team_id, class_name: 'Event'
  has_many :away_events, foreign_key: :away_team_id, class_name: 'Event'
  has_many :medias, as: :mediable
  belongs_to :university

  validates_presence_of :name, :sport_type

  # scope :by_university, ->(university_id) { where(team_id: team_id).order(name: name) }
  # scope :find_team, -> { Team.find_by id: id }
  # scope :by_sport_type, ->(sport_type) { Team.where(sport_type: sport_type) }
  # scope :with_university, joins: :teams 
  # def self.by_university(university_id)
  #   University.where(id: 1)
  #   University.joins(:teams).where(teams: { name: name })
  # end

  def self.by_university
    University.where(university_id: university_id).first
  end

  def self.university_join
    University.joins(:teams)
  end

  def self.by_sport_type(sport_type)
    where(sport_type: sport_type)
  end

  def self.baseball
    by_sport_type('Baseball/Softball')
  end
end
```

university.rb

```
  class University < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :address, :city, :name, :state, :url, :zip

  has_many :teams, dependent: :destroy

  validates :zip, presence: true, format: { with: /\A\d{5}(-\d+)?\z/ },
            length: { minimum: 5 }
  validates_presence_of :name, :address, :city, :state, :url

  scope :universities, -> { University.order(name: 'ASC') }
  # scope :by_teams, ->(university_id) { Team.find_by_university_id(university_id) }
  # scope :team_by_university, ->(team_id) { where(team_id: team_id).order(name: name)}

  def sport_type
    team.sport_type
  end
end
```

views/teams/index.html.erb

[Placed in gists for formatting reasons](https://gist.github.com/sirramongabriel/7763245)

## rake routes output: (in a public gist)

[enter link description here](https://gist.github.com/sirramongabriel/7763415)

## rails console

[image]

Comment: You're not supplying a university ID in `params[:university_id]`, so `University.find(params[:university_id])` is `University.find(nil)`, hence the error. Normally if you wanted to scope teams by a university, you would nest teams inside universities in your routes, giving you a route like `/universities/12/teams`.

Comment: Didn't think about that, routes.rb appended to end of question.

Comment: Hello Sevenseacat, my only thoughts would be that I would instead pass params[:id]. When I edited the University.find(params[:university_id] to University.find(params[:id] The error persists. Any thoughts?

Comment: you're not supplying params[:id] either.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean by not supplying params[:id] or params[:university_id]. I've included a console image displaying both team and universities params. I'm sure I'm missing something silly, but I'm at a loss. Any further explanation is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not going to want to have both:

```
resources :universities  #lose this one

resources :universities do 
  resources :teams 
end
```

As for params... you have to give a param.  So, when you go to `http://localhost:3000/teams` there are no params, by default.  If you go to `http://localhost:3000/teams/3` then `params[:id] = 3` and this will pull up your third team.

Keep in mind the nomenclature of an index.  The index action of Teams, is going to list all of the teams.  All of them.  There is no one University there, so what are you actually trying to find?  If anything, you'd have, for your University controller:

```
def show
  @university = University.find(params[:id])
  @teams = @university.teams
end
```

so, the address bar will be showing `http://localhost:3000/universities/23`, right?  params[:id] = 23, then you can find the teams associated with that university.

Comment: The author is referencing the route `university_teams GET    /universities/:university_id/teams(.:format)`, so indeed `params[:university_id]` should be used.

Comment: Thank you Mallanaga for the 'teams/index' description, makes sense.